# Trying to Poke my Android and Turn on the Screen Programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, timer

I am building an alarm kind of application for Android.

I set a certain timer to run and then fire after a certain time interval (after the user presses a button) which I call in the onCreate method.

```
final int interval = 20000; // 20 Second
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
      public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer to Wake",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
      }
};

handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

I've also disabled the keyboard in the onCreate method with:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

In the Android developer docs, it says:

> Window flag: when set as a window is being added or made visible, once the window has been shown then the system will **poke** the power manager's user activity (as if the user had woken up the device) to turn the screen on.

Now after I fire the timer with a press of the button, I immediately turn off the screen. After waiting 20 second though, the screen isn't poked and the device doesn't awaken. What could be the issue here? When I do turn on the screen though with the power button after waiting another 20 seconds, I do find that the keyboard is disabled. Also the screen is perpetually awake when I do leave the screen on. So I know the flags are working. I just need it to "wake" up when the timer fires!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to properly group the right methods in the correct area. I had previously split the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON in different areas.

To successfully turn on the screen:

```
public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer to Wake", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent`

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getApplicationContext getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),(9 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I want this. I just want to know how to wake the screen with what methods I have now.